# How to label occurences of text (regex, sed, awk) (Linux)

Tags: regex, bash, numbers, label

I would like to convert

```
blue blue red green
```

to:

```
color.1=blue color.2=blue color.3=red color.4=green
```

Any leads on how to tackle this? Sed, awk, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
s='blue blue red green'
echo -n "$s"|awk -v RS=' ' '{printf "color." NR "=" $0 OFS} END{print ""}'
color.1=blue color.2=blue color.3=red color.4=green
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with something easy like:

```
$ awk -F' ' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { printf("%s=%s\n", i, $i); } }'
1=blue
2=blue
3=red
4=green
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `perl` for that:

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/"color." . ++$n . "=$&"/ge'
```